# Ground Induced Currents on Mars

Tags: mars, magnetic-field, solar-storm

Since Mars is only weakly magnetized does Mars not suffer from  ground induced currents or are they far worse than on Earth?

Answer (score 1):

There is no net internal magnetic field to perturb, so how could one induce currents?

The effect arises on Earth because some transient event (e.g., [coronal mass ejection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) or CME) hits Earth's [magnetosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere) and causes a sudden $\tfrac{dB}{dt}$ which, from Faraday's law, results in induced electric fields.  These induced electric fields then drive currents in things like power grids (typically long-distance wires running east-west at high latitudes), oil pipelines, etc.

The only changing magnetic field would be that of the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) and the small, localized [magnetic anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_anomaly) on the surface of Mars.  However, these fields are incredibly small so the $\tfrac{dB}{dt}$ would be even smaller.